# What does this numpy code snippet do?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
float(multiply(colVec1,colVec2).T * (matrix*matrix[i,:].T)) + c
```

I am new to Python and numpy and I am trying to understand what the code snippet above does.

The `multiply().T` part performs an element-by-element multiplication and then does a transpose, and so the result becomes a row vector.

I am trying to understand what `matrix[i,:]` does. Does it create a sub-matrix by picking just the i'th row vector or does it create a sub-matrix from the i'th row vector all the way to the end of the matrix?

The `*` performs a dot-product which is then converted to a float using `float()`.

Comment: A crucial question is whether `matrix` is a regular numpy array (2d) or a `np.matrix` subclass.  I'm guessing the 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `matrix[i, :]` will give you the i:th **row** of `matrix` since the `:` means "pick all in this dimension".

And no, `A * B` is not the dot product between `A` and `B`, it is the **element-wise product** of `A` and `B`.
To get the dot product you would use any of

```
A.dot(B)
np.dot(A, B)
A @ B           # Python 3.5+ only
```

The above is true as long as you use the `np.ndarray` class, which you did if you created your matrices/arrays using `np.array`, `np.eye`, `np.zeros`, etc.
There is also a `np.matrix` class where the multiplication operator `*` is actually the dot product, but it is strongly adviced to *never* use it since it tends to create confusion when mixed with the normal array type.

#### So what is going on in the expression?

Lets's break it down to parts.

`multiply(colVec1,colVec2).T` will create the transpose of the element-wise product of `colVec1` and `colVec2`.

`matrix*matrix[i,:].T` is the element-wise product between `matrix` and the transpose of the i:th row of `matrix`. Due to numpys broadcasting rules this is actually the same as multiplying (elementwise) each row of `matrix` with its i:th row.

What we can see now is that both these expressions will create a matrix/array and not a scalar.
Therefore the call to `float()` will fail, as it expects a 1-element array or scalar.

My verdict is that someone has either been using the `np.matrix` class, or has interpreted the use of `*` wrong.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is the code snippet in the question doing? The result of everything in `float()` is a scalar and I am trying to understand how :)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Short answer: the code should not work (in general) as the argument to `float()` will not be a scalar.

Comment: Also, in the future, if you are unsure about what a piece of code does, the easiest way to find out is to simply run it in the interpreter.

Comment: So if it is `np.matrix` class, the `*` becomes a dot product and thus a scalar in `float()`.

Comment: If the dimensions of   the `colVec`s and `matrix` agree, then yes.

Comment: The `matrix` was created using [`mat()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mat.html) and `colVec`s using `zeroes()`.  In this case the result will be an array and not a scalar, right?

Comment: No. Which you can easily verify by running the code yourself. Although the left `colVec` part is (supposedly) an array, the multiplication with the right `matrix` part will be executed as the dot product since one part is a matrix type. All this is actually a stellar showcase of why the `np.matrix` classes should be avoided.